# Filter A Tilepanel javafx

Tags: java, filter, lambda

I need a help to filter a tilepane content.

My tilepane contains  stackpanes and each  stackpanes  contains an ImageView and Text

TilePane ----- StackPane   ---------- ImageView + Text
          \
           \  StackPane -------------ImageView + Text

I need to show only StackPanes which their Text contain "Pickme"

```
tilePaneImage.getChildren().filtered( s -> ((Text)((StackPane) s).getChildren().get(1)).getText().toLowerCase().contains(txtFiltre.getText().toLowerCase())) ;
```

=> No errors and pictures are not filtered

```
tilePaneImage.getChildren().filtered( (s) -> {
if(  ((Text)         ((StackPane)s).getChildren().get(1)).getText().toLowerCase().contains(txtFiltre.    getText().toLowerCase())) {System.out.println("Show");return true;}
  System.out.println("Hide");
  return false;
  });
```

==> console shows some ("Hide") but the TilePane  still show all StackPane  .

Comment: I guess, it’s because neither printing `"Hide"` to the console nor filtering a list causes JavaFX to hide components. Without changing an appropriate property of a component, you won’t cause visual changes to the UI.

Comment: Thanks i know that printing a String will not hide anything that helps me alot :D.

Comment: I used     tilePaneImage.getChildren().setAll(filteredList);     to refresh  UI and it workes.

Comment: @mils can you post a full answer ,because I failed to filter a tilepane.